# HTML page load time

Tags: php, html, ajax, time, load

Hi guys I got a small problem. I got some site which get displayed on handheld computers. Those computers are SLOW. Even though they cost 4 figures they have Windows CE5/CE6 and 300-800 MHz CPUs.

Those handhelds are running a php based database application. We already minimized the javascript to speed it up but now the raw html data just takes too much time to get displayed. Sometimes only 1-10 records of the database are getting displayed thats not much of a problem. But around xmas our client has much more to do so we end up with 100+ records.

I'm already trying to minimize the html per record like shorter class/id names etc. Doesn't do much but it sums up on 100+ records.

I wonder if someone has some other ideas. Some other ideas of mine would be to display only a fixed amount and implement some system for multiple pages or load the data via ajax requests after the site was rendered. Anyone has some better ideas? Atm it takes up to 5-10 secs for the page to get displayed and if u have to work on 100+ records where some guy has to work on and you have 20-30 workers it sums up, so our client isn't pretty happy with the situation.

Comment: You could use pagination to stop so many loading onto one page, but if you want it to run smoothly, ajax would be your best bet.

Comment: Are you sure its the html causing issues, and not the database or network latency? Sounds unlikely to me.

Comment: What times are you getting from PC? Maybe your host is slow? Share some code.

Comment: Around 1 sec via VPN. Network is fine.

Comment: Try run Yslow (Mozilla Extension) and see results

Comment: Already tried that not much of a help. Tells me to reduce HTTP request which won't happen cuz some modules only use some of them and downloading a big file everytime wouldn't speed it up but makes it slower on nearly all other sites. Same goes for the css at the body, which only gets included when that page is loaded. At the end the 100+ KB html file is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is it definitely not the queries taking the time to load? Can you try loading it in a proper browser on a PC? Try using the Chrome developer tools to find out exactly which bits are taking time to load, and exactly what is using the most memory etc.

Comment: Load time on a normal PC via VPN on my clients webserver is 1,14 seconds. The query takes 0,2 sec. Network is fine we already had problems with those computers while using a js framework like prototype. Already wrote all functions ourself to speed it up.